# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 128, 2), found shape=(128, 2, 128)

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have been working on a deep learning model in tensorflow as given below. I have the dataset that I'm trying to feed into the model but it gives me a dimension error as given below

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, label, test_size = 0.2, random_state=1)
x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(x_train, y_train,test_size = 0.2, random_state=1)

print(x_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
```

(161280, 2, 128)
(161280,)

```
model = models.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Input(shape=(2,128)))

model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))

model.add(layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=2))

model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))

model.add(layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=2))

model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))

model.add(layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=2))

model.add(layers.Flatten())

model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))

model.add(layers.Dense(11, activation = 'softmax'))

#Training

callbacks= [
keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(
monitor="val_loss", factor=0.1, patience=8, min_lr=0.001),
keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", patience=5, verbose=1)
]

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.007)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=4, verbose=2, validation_data= (x_val, y_val), callbacks=callbacks)
```

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'conv1d' (type Conv1D).

```
Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 2 for '{{node sequential/conv1d/Conv1D}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](sequential/conv1d/Conv1D/ExpandDims, sequential/conv1d/Conv1D/ExpandDims_1)' with input shapes: [128,1,2,128], [1,3,128,64].
```

I tried giving the input shape as (128,2) but that doesnt work either. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are using **Conv1D** with kernel size 3 for the input shape of 2 dim which is causing negative dimension size error.

You can use `padding='same'` in Conv1D layers as well as decrease the `pool_size=1` for second and other Maxpool1D layer to fix this issue.

Please check below code for example:

```
model.add(layers.Input(shape=(2,128)))

model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))
model.add(layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=2))

model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))
model.add(layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=1))
.
.
.
```

(Attached the replicated [gist](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/fc648acbeb84678e8650f7cec414ed2e/76321845.ipynb#scrollTo=Rrg4uHIaLbSh) here for your reference.)